# Graphs that executed fine in Rstudio aren't working on Kaggle. Why?

Tags: r, graph, r-markdown, kaggle

I have previously run the below code in Rstudio without any problem. You can check out the whole notebook [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/trevorbaudin/cyclistic-trevor-01/notebook).

Here is the code that is not working on Kaggle:

```r
pie_type_user <- data.frame(rider_type = c("Member", "Casual"), 
                            values = c(2189031, 1537785))

ggplot(pie_type_user, aes(x = "", y = values, fill = rider_type)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    labs(fill = "Rider Type") +
    ggtitle("Rides Per Year") +
    theme_void() +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::comma(values)), 
                  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Here is the message I am receiving:

```r
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in grid.newpage(): 
    could not open file 'Rplot001.png'

Traceback:

    tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
    . if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr))
    . stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
    . rpr <- repr::mime2repr[mime]
    . if (is.null(rpr))
    . return(NULL)
    . prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
    . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
    tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
    tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
    doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
    withCallingHandlers({
    . if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr))
    . stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
    . rpr <- repr::mime2repr[mime]
    . if (is.null(rpr))
    . return(NULL)
    . prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
    . }, error = error_handler)
    repr::mime2repr[mime]
    repr_text.default(obj)
    paste(capture.output(print(obj)), collapse = "\n")
    capture.output(print(obj))
    evalVis(expr)
    withVisible(eval(expr, pf))
    eval(expr, pf)
    eval(expr, pf)
    print(obj)
    print.ggplot(obj)
    grid.newpage()
```

Thoughts? Suggestions?

I haven't found any threads that provide solutions to this problem and I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 1):

I run into same problem and just found the solution.

If you used setwd() to set a new directory to read csv file, remember to **set the work directory back to the default** one by `setwd('/kaggle/working')`

or **please do not change your working directory** and just read your csv files from "../input"